# How to simulate a etas spatio-temporal model?

Tags: simulation, prediction, point-process

My question is how simulate the spatio-temporal ETAS point process (a point process used for earthquake prediction) defined by a conditional intensity function. More precisely: let $\mathbf{V}$ be a spatio temporal point process, $\mathbf{s}$ be a vector of dimension 2 containing the coordinates,  $t$ be the temporal index and $m$ indicates a threshold level for the earthquake.

In the ETAS model the intensity (conditional) function is 
\begin{equation}
\lambda(\mathbf{s},t,m|\mathcal{H}(t))= \lambda(\mathbf{s},t|\mathcal{H}(t))\Gamma(m) = \left(\mu(\mathbf{s})+ \rho \sum_{i:t_i<t}\alpha(m_i)g(t-t_i)f(||\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{s}_i || | m_i)\right)\Gamma(m)
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{H}(t)$ is the history of earthquake until time $t$, $t$ excluded.  $\mu(\mathbf{s})$ is the background intensity and could be function on coordinates and some covariates:
\begin{equation}
\mu(\mathbf{s}) = \mathbf{Z} \boldsymbol{\eta}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{Z}$ is the matrix of covariate (possible with $\mathbf{s}$) and $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ is the vector of regressor coefficients.
 $\alpha(m)$ is the expected number of events triggered from an event of magnitude $m$:
\begin{equation}
\alpha(m) = \exp(\psi (m-\bar{m}))
\end{equation} 
where $\bar{m}$ is a threshold magnitude (events over this threshold are not take into consideration in the model). $g(t-t_i)$ is the probability density function of the occurrence times of the triggered events:
\begin{equation}
g(t-t_i) =  \frac{\beta_2-1}{\beta_1}\left(1+\frac{t}{\beta_1}\right)^{-\beta_2}
\end{equation} 
The locations distribution of the triggered events we use is
\begin{equation}
f(||\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{s}_i || | m_i) =  \frac{\xi-1}{\pi \delta^2\exp(\omega (m-\bar{m}))} \exp\left(  1+ \frac{(\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{s}_i)^{\prime}(\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{s}_i)}{\delta^2\exp(\omega (m-\bar{m}))}  \right)^{- \xi}
\end{equation} 
other choice are possible. Finally 
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(m) = \gamma \exp (\gamma (m-\bar{m}))
\end{equation}
Then the log-likelihood is 
\begin{equation}
\log L(\mathbf{V}| \mathcal{H}(t_1)) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda(\mathbf{s}_i,t_i,m_i|\mathcal{H}(t_i))-\int_{ \mathcal{T}_B} \int_{ \mathcal{S}_B} \int_{\mathcal{M}_b} \lambda\left( \mathbf{s}, t ,m|  \mathcal{H}(t) \right) d \mathbf{s} d t d m
\end{equation}

Comment: There are some R packages for this goal such as PtProcess or ETAS. I am also working on this topic and have some problems. I appreciate if you could give me your email address to discuss this issue more.

Comment: I sent you an email.